# Mutate with group by and case by checking non NA in r

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to insert column Text based on non NA condition with group by category and type in R with below code. Test1 is my resulting data frame. But group by is not happening.

```
Category=c("A","A","A","B","B","B")
Type=c("P","P","R","S","S","S")
Col1=c("ABCD","","","","wxyz","")
Col2=c("","","MTNL","","","")
Col3=c("","PQRS","","","","")
Col4=c("","","","","","")
Col5=c("","","","","","")
Col6=c("","","","","","EFGH")
Test=data.frame(Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6)

Text=c("PQRS","PQRS","MTNL","EFGH","EFGH","EFGH")
Test1=data.frame(Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Text)

Test1=Test %>%
  group_by(Category, Type) %>% 
  mutate(
    Text = case_when(
      !is.na(`Col6`) ~ `Col6`,
      !is.na(`Col5`) ~ `Col5`,
      !is.na(`Col4`) ~ `Col4`,
      !is.na(`Col3`) ~ `Col3`,
      !is.na(`Col2`) ~ `Col2`,
      !is.na(`Col1`) ~ `Col1`,
      TRUE                      ~  as.character(NA)
    )
  )
```

Can someone help me out to solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have blank values and not `NA` values so checking with `is.na` will not work. You should do :

```
library(dplyr)

Test %>%
  group_by(Category, Type) %>% 
  mutate(
    Text = case_when(
      Col6 != '' ~ Col6,
      Col5 != '' ~ Col5,
      Col4 != '' ~ Col4,
      Col3 != '' ~ Col3,
      Col2 != '' ~ Col2,
      Col1 != '' ~ Col1,
      TRUE ~  NA_character_
    )
  )

# Category Type  Col1   Col2   Col3   Col4  Col5  Col6   Text 
#  <chr>    <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr>
#1 A        P     "ABCD" ""     ""     ""    ""    ""     ABCD 
#2 A        P     ""     ""     "PQRS" ""    ""    ""     PQRS 
#3 A        R     ""     "MTNL" ""     ""    ""    ""     MTNL 
#4 B        S     ""     ""     ""     ""    ""    ""     NA   
#5 B        S     "wxyz" ""     ""     ""    ""    ""     wxyz 
#6 B        S     ""     ""     ""     ""    ""    "EFGH" EFGH
```

But this doesn't give your expected answer as well since `case_when` operates rowwise. Here is one way to solve this for multiple such `Col` variables without writing individual columns.

```
Test %>%
  group_by(Category, Type) %>%
  summarise(across(starts_with('Col'), ~.x[.x!=''][1])) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(Text = coalesce(!!! rev(select(., starts_with('Col'))))) %>%
  select(Category, Type, Text) %>%
  left_join(Test1, by  = c('Category', 'Type')) %>%
  select(everything(), -Text, Text)

#  Category Type  Col1   Col2   Col3   Col4  Col5  Col6   Text 
#  <chr>    <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr>
#1 A        P     "ABCD" ""     ""     ""    ""    ""     PQRS 
#2 A        P     ""     ""     "PQRS" ""    ""    ""     PQRS 
#3 A        R     ""     "MTNL" ""     ""    ""    ""     MTNL 
#4 B        S     ""     ""     ""     ""    ""    ""     EFGH 
#5 B        S     "wxyz" ""     ""     ""    ""    ""     EFGH 
#6 B        S     ""     ""     ""     ""    ""    "EFGH" EFGH
```

**data**

```
Test=data.frame(Category, Type, Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6)
```

Comment: How do I deal the same problem with NA values instead of blank values in cell?

Comment: In `summarise` change this part`~.x[.x!=''][1])` to `~na.omit(.x)[1]`

Comment: Thank You so much. Solution worked perfectly. @Ronak Shah